# Area of Polygon - spyder

Tags: python, polygon, area, spyder

I have a really hard task to do, which is to calculate the area of the polygon using earlier created script in PYTHON to read the data from a set of Polygons stored in Well Known Text format and calculate the area for each Polygon using the formula..(I don't know the actual formula... I know it's theformula to calculate the area of a polygon using the summation of triangles.)

then script should read the data from the file and store it as a list or lists. The script should compute the polygon area and save the areas of each polygon to a file and also script should use a function to calculate the area of the polygon.

Please help, as I have no idea how to do it in python(never used it before). You are my last chance people!

Comment: Include sample inputs and outputs if you hope to find a code monkey to do your work for you!

Comment: assuming you have 2 lists for x and y variables eg.
x = [1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0]
y = [1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0]
The area of this polygon would be 16 (4 x 4 square)

Comment: Hi @user3047214 - Welcome to stack overflow. If you have a question that involves any code at all, then you should follow this guide, http://sscce.org/ And read and understand this: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shapely library to calculate the area.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely

Create a Polygon using the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon.

```
poly = Polygon([list of point pairs])
```

The area of the polygon is returned by:

```
poly.area
```